# Apache2 won't restart (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: 16.04, server, apache2, wordpress

I am reasonably new to using server computers and running into bumps every now and then which I then have to figure out, but that is part of the fun of learning.

Right now I'm trying to set up a wordpress website, but apache2 doesn't seem to want to reload after I configured the wordpress site.

when I use systemctl status apache2.service, I get the following response:

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-04-28 14:49:40 CEST; 10min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 56053 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 28 14:49:40 ubuntuServerAlex apache2[56053]:  *
Apr 28 14:49:40 ubuntuServerAlex apache2[56053]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Apr 28 14:49:40 ubuntuServerAlex apache2[56053]: Output of config test was:
Apr 28 14:49:40 ubuntuServerAlex apache2[56053]: apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/authz_svn.load: Syntax error on line 6 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Apr 28 14:49:40 ubuntuServerAlex apache2[56053]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Apr 28 14:49:40 ubuntuServerAlex apache2[56053]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Apr 28 14:49:40 ubuntuServerAlex systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 28 14:49:40 ubuntuServerAlex systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Apr 28 14:49:40 ubuntuServerAlex systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Apr 28 14:49:40 ubuntuServerAlex systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Does anyone know what the issue is and how I could fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your apache can not load module. Becouse of that can not start

```
mod_dav_svn.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Just try do update/upgrade

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade libapache2-svn
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```